# Design different signatures with same name in derived classes

Tags: design-patterns, inheritance, .net-3.5

I want to achieve static calls like `File.XLS.Export(columnNames, dbNames);` or `File.CSV.Export(delimiter, columnNames, dbNames);`

By now I designed a abstract class and let CSV and XLS inherit from it.
As you can see I may need a different signature when using a CSV export. I could do an overload, but I don't want to see that overload in the XLS export, because it's totally useless there.

So how can I hide this specific implementation in my XLS export? Are there maybe any patterns I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some approaches I'm going to do it with ExtensionMethods. It seems to fit best into our environment.

Answer (score 2):

I would say check out the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  It boils down to two concrete implementations of the same abstraction should be interchangeable.  If you swap an XLS for a CSV implementation in your example, you have to change source code.

```
 // Some client code
 // it has to be aware of differing implementations, so if this changes to CSV
 // this code changes
 File exported = XLS.export(columnNames, dbNames);
```

Rather than using static methods, I would favor an approach where XLSExporter and CSVExporter both derive from the same base class and have the same exactly the same interface.  I'm a Java guy but you should be able to get the idea:

```
 public interface Exporter {
    public File export();
 }

 public class XLSExporter implements Exporter {
    public XLSExporter(String[] columns, String[] databases) // specifics go in constructor

    public File export() // ...
 }

 public class CSVExporter implements Exporter {
    public CSVExporter(String delim, String[] columns, String[] databases) // specifics go in constructor

    public File export() // ...
 }
```

Now clients of an Exporter don't need to be aware of differing arguments.  They just export with whatever they are handed.  This will make your code for flexible and maintainable.

```
 // new client code
 // doesn't care about what kind of exporter it is, it just executes what it's given
 File exported = exporter.export();
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, but I need to do it static because all of our existing base functions are static.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the two functions to be static, then you don't need inheritance. Just make a single class and stick two different static functions in it, with different signatures and different implementations. I think you are over-engineering it, particularly when considering the unique constraint imposed on you by your existing codebase to have the functions static.

Comment: You are right. That's why I came to the conclusion to use Extension Methods. All I wanted were same method names in both classes.
But now I'm going for (overloaded) .ToXLS and .ToCSV